# Bind Collection To PageReference Parameter?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, url, parameters

I have a list of 15 record ids. I converted it into string (comma seperated value). Now I want to pass this string using pageReference but in url it gives only 10 records. What can I do?

Code:

```
 for(string mapkey:m1.keyset())
                          {
                          system.debug(mapkey);
                          listid.add(mapkey);
                          }
```

Controller:

```
PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/repeatcon');
  String mapString = String.valueOf(m1.keyset());
                     system.debug(mapString);
                    pageRef.getParameters().put('idmap', mapString);

          for(string mapkey:m1.keyset())
          {
          system.debug(mapkey);
          }


    return pageRef;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `String.valueOf` on a collection, you will experience truncation after the tenth element. You should instead use the `String.join` method to perform a comma join.

```
List<String> ids = new List<String>(m1.keySet());
pageRef.getParameters().put('idmap', String.join(ids, ','));
```

Then to parse it, you can just do:

```
String idParam = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('idmap');
List<String> ids = (idParam == null) ? new List<String>() : idParam.split(',');
```